# Moodle autologin plugin - how to direct user to a specific course?

Tags: laravel, api, plugins, moodle

I am  building a laravel web application which involves the usage of Moodle Service (version 3.6). I have done autologin with a [plugin](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_userkey).

The problem is that clicking the **Take Course** button on my external application will autologin to Moodle (via the plugin), but does not redirect the user to the course described in the button.

Is there a mechanism to do this?

Comment: Improved overall readability. Focused title more on the problem.

Comment: Do you have a control over the plugin? I'd advise to pass some url parameter like `course_id` or similar to the login plugin and handle that parameter on successful login.

Comment: Can you post the code of autologin? (What happens when Take course is clicked) also how the course link is constructed?

Answer (score 3):

The plugin you are using already has an option to do this:

See the `user_login_userkey()` method [here](https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_userkey/blob/MOODLE_33PLUS/auth.php)

```
/**
 * Logs a user in using userkey and redirects after.
 *
 */
public function user_login_userkey() {

    $keyvalue = required_param('key', PARAM_ALPHANUM);
    $wantsurl = optional_param('wantsurl', '', PARAM_URL);

    if (!empty($wantsurl)) {
        $redirecturl = $wantsurl;
    } else {
        $redirecturl = $CFG->wwwroot;
    }
    if (isloggedin()) {
        $this->redirect($redirecturl);
    }
```

So you only need to pass the `wantsurl` parameter having the course URL and it should automatically redirect you to the course after login.

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin github page you linked, I noticed the section:

```
if (isset($courseid)) {
        $path = '&wantsurl=' . urlencode("$domainname/course/view.php?id=$courseid");
    }
    if (isset($modname) && isset($activityid)) {
        $path = '&wantsurl=' . urlencode("$domainname/mod/$modname/view.php?id=$activityid");
    }
```

I believe you can define a redirect url after the login by adding the `wantsurl` query parameter to your login url.